# C# overriding old objects in a loop

Tags: c#, memory, loops

I have a loop storing creating objects and storing them. There is 3 classes, and a lot of code so I will give the highlights:
In the main class:

```
 public static List<TaskIDHolder> mainHolders = new List<TaskIDHolder> ();
```

My loop works like this:

```
 foreach (string aDir in directories){
 //Variables
 string var1= "";
 int var2= 0;

 //Buisness Logic


 //Storage
        Boolean newTaskID = true;
        foreach (TaskIDHolder taskIDHolder in mainHolders)
        {
            if (taskIDHolder.getTaskID().Equals(taskID))
            {
                //Add obj
                File newFile = new File(var1, var2);
                taskIDHolder.addFile(newFile);
                newTaskID = false;
            }
        }
        if (newTaskID)
        {
            //Create Holder
            File newFile = new File(var1, var2);
            TaskIDHolder newHolder = new TaskIDHolder(taskID, newFile);
            //Add Holder
            mainHolders.Add(newHolder);
        }    

 }
```

Now my other classes are File and TaskIDHolder. Now I get 9 instances of the same file in the TaskIDHolder, instead of different instances.

EDIT: Sorry, my question is how can I get unique instances of File objects stored.

I did not write the Business Logic down because it bring no insight to the question.

As for the classes here they are:

```
class File
{
    public static string var1;
    public static int var2;

    public File(string avar1, int avar2)
    {
        var1 = avar1;
        var2 = avar2;
    }

    public string getVar1()
    {
        return var1;
    }

    public int getVar2()
    {
        return var2;
    }
}

class TaskIDHolder
{
    public static List<File> files = null;
    public static string taskID = "";

    public TaskIDHolder(string aTaskID, File aFile)
    {
        taskID = aTaskID;
        files = new List<File>();
        files.Add(aFile);
    }

    public void addFile(File aFile)
    {
        files.Add(aFile);
    }

    public string getTaskID()
    {
        return taskID;
    }

    public List<File> getFiles()
    {
        return files;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me - I strongly suggest you write a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. Currently we can't see your File or TaskIDHolder classes.

Comment: You are looping over the same list (`mainHolders`) for each directory. Is this what you want?

Comment: What are var1 and var2 for? You are never changing them.

Comment: Where does "taskID" come from ?

Comment: I think you need to break in the inner foreach loop after you set newTaskID = false;

Answer (score 1):

You're **probabbly** asking for something like (pseudocode):

```
 if (newTaskID)
 {
   //find a file in the collection
   File newFile = taskIDHolder.Where(file=>file.Var1 == var1 && file.Var2==var2).SingleOrDefault<File>();

   //can not find it, so create a new one
   if(newFile==null)
       newFile = new File(var1, var2);

   TaskIDHolder newHolder = new TaskIDHolder(taskID, newFile);
   //Add Holder
   mainHolders.Add(newHolder);
  }
```

Please note that I **supposed** that `File` object has `Var1` and `Var2` properties. If not, pick up correct properties for your type.

Comment: You need to replace `Single` with `SingleOrDefault` otherwise you'll get an exception if there isn't any

Comment: I am not asking for that, I am asking why my File objects variables are all being overridden to the last isntance of my File.

Comment: @AmiramKorach: oopps, corrcted, thx.

Comment: @PeterP: cause, **probbably** (it's hard deduct from the code), but `vasr1` and `var2` are refernce type variables, and you **do not** recreate them on every new `File` object creation, so all `File`s are pointing to the *same* pair of `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: I agree Tigran, but why is it that a new instance of var1 and var2 is not created in the loop.

Comment: Should I be editting my File class or my loop to fix this?

Comment: @Peter: your loop, I think. Check where new instance has to be created.